# What to do with stock bonus given by the employer?

Tags: fiqh, sadaqah, investment

I work at Walmart which sells guns,pork and alcohol. Company gives us stocks bonus either we like it or not.

My question is :what to do with thsee stocks,should I sell them and give away all the money, to who and where?
Can I give to masjid or Muslim family in need?.
Or give percent of it?.
How much of the percentage should I take away &how much should I keep?

Please give detailed answer in a eas way so I and other can understand it.jazakAllah khair for your help

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. As for your question title consider reading in our [Meta](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1837/advice-for-writing-question-titles-on-islam-se).Also please don't confound us with a fatwa site see for example [here](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3256/examining-fatwa-request-questions) and [here](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1815/giving-help-or-fatwa-or-advice-or-what) in our meta. Note that any person able to use the internet might post an answer here!